# ASP.NET Core Mobile Back-end API [Error]: This appname.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy an newly created ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure services using `Publish -> Create New App Service` but even though the Azure Portal displays the newly created app and its service plan I can't open it in the browser dialing the URL and neither the Postman return anything in a GET request.

*Yet, It perfectly works in the localhost*

It'll be kind of you if someone can tell me how to deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure Cloud which will be the back-end for a Xamarin.Android RESTful Service.

Thanks in adance

Comment: When you push an ASP.NET Web Application to an Azure Web Site, Kudu builds it by using msbuild to create deployment artifacts.
In some cases, it's possible to have a Web Application that runs fine from VS, but that becomes broken when you use msbuild to deploy it. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally

 A runtime issue happens when the files in your wwwroot folder are exactly what they should be, but for some reason the site doesn't run correctly: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues#runtime-issues

Comment: Hi @Ajay Thanks a lot for your comment which added some knowledge about Kudu in Azure for my knowledge but here what happened was that I haven't set a default file in the creation so if I directly call the API url Eg: 'localhost/api/<controller>' then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for an solution throughout the internet and finally found a working one in [Microsoft Blog by benjaminperkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/21/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-core-1-1-application-to-an-azure-app-services-web-app-using-visual-studio-2017/) it says

> To resolve the 404 when accessing an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API you need to append the URL with /api/values

and this works perfectly, yet some modifications will be needed based on your objectives.

Thanks, 
TS

Answer (score -1):

For anyone working with Azure Functions:

You can get the same error if you created your function app as .net Core 3 and then deploy functions to it that were developed using .net Core 6.